# jQuery click event not working while using "Module Pattern"

Tags: javascript, jquery, module

I'm an intermediate front-end JS developer and I'm trying the Module Pattern outlined by Chris Coyyer [here](http://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/).

But when I store a jQuery selector in the settings, I'm unable to use it to trigger a click event. See the below code with my comments... Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
var s,
TestWidget = {
  settings: {
    testButton: $("#testing")
  },
  init: function() {
    s = this.settings;
    this.bindUIActions();
  },
  bindUIActions: function() {
    console.log(s.testButton); // This works: [context: document, selector: "#testing", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]

    //This doesn't work - why?????
    s.testButton.click(function() {
        //Why isn't this triggered?
        alert('testButton clicked');
    });

    /*This works, obviously:
    $('#testing').click(function() {
        alert('testButton clicked');
    });
    */

  }
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    TestWidget.init();
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you initialize `$("#testing")` before the DOM is ready, so this jQuery object is empty.

A simple solution is to put all your code in the ready callback.

Another one would be to replace

```
  settings: {
    testButton: $("#testing")
  },
  init: function() {
    s = this.settings;
    this.bindUIActions();
  },
```

with

```
  settings: {
  },
  init: function() {
    s = this.settings;
    s.testButton = $("#testing");
    this.bindUIActions();
  },
```

But it's hard to get why you use so much code for such a simple thing. You might be overusing the pattern here and it's not really clean as you have two global variables `s` and `TestWidget` when one would already be a lot.

Here's a slight variation of your code which would be, in my opinion, cleaner, while still using modules ([IIFE variant](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)) :

```
TestWidget = (function(){
    var settings = {};
    return {
        init: function() {
            settings.testButton = $("#testing");
            this.bindUIActions();
        },
        bindUIActions: function() {
            console.log(settings.testButton);
            settings.testButton.click(function() {
                alert('testButton clicked');
            });
        }
    }

})();
$(document).ready(function() {
    TestWidget.init();
});
```

`settings` is kept in the closure and doesn't leak in the global namespace. Note that even this version doesn't make sense if you don't do more with the module.

Comment: I think op was simply following the example on CSS tricks to understand the pattern.  Perhaps there is a larger task at hand?  If the intent is to understand encapsulation via modularization, I recommend reading design patterns by addy osmani.

Comment: Placing the script blocks at the bottom of the page, after all content, would resolve this problem. This would enable the code to be placed entirely within the module with no leakage to the global namespace.

Comment: @ChrisCamaratta When you use modules, you probably also place your JS code in separate files.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! I ended up moving the module to the bottom of the page. @stavarotti is correct to assume I'm learning the basics to tackle larger projects. Thanks again!